# Designing circuit in Eagle with two boards and ribbon cable

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

In order to fit my circuit in my enclosure neatly I need to create it as two PCBs connected by ribbon cable. It's logically one circuit. It certainly makes sense two design it using a single schematic. And ideally I'd like to have both boards in the same .brd file, I think this will make it easier to visualize and maintain the board layout. How should I arrange the board file? Should I draw a second rectangle on the dimension layer to represent the second board? Or maybe draw one rectangle and then draw a line thru it to divide it in two? I've been using PCBWay for production and I understand they support V-Scoring and Tab Routing, are these a good solution for my case and if so, where could i find info on how to define them using Eagle?

Related to this, I'm wondering how to indicate a ribbon cable (or any inter-board connection) in such a way that while it will form a logical part of the schematic Eagle won't draw airwires between my boards. The airwires will simply go to the connectors where the ribbon cable terminates.

I really appreciate any guidance. I'm quite new to Eagle and I'm not sure where to look for more info on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this

put in pin header holes, run traces between them so that there is continuity in the schematic (i had to use the fuse symbol in the editor)

then v-score between the boards

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHlAUa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If your board should be manufactured, just ask your supplier.
The dimension layer is used to draw the board outline, if there are two boards, just draw two rectangles or whatever shape is necessary.
Some years ago I designed a small battery powered sensor circuit. The whole thing should have the shape of a cylinder. I used three circular stacked boards connected with several wires parallel to the axis of the cylinder. I used only one circuit and one board file. The connection between the boards was drawn on an additional reserved routing layer not used for board production. This layer was only used to avoid missing routes errors.
You may use an additional reserved routing layer for the connections with the ribbon cable. Just document it clearly to avoid any misunderstandings during manufacture.